# Does sending a CRSF token with ajax request weaken its CRSF protection

Tags: php, ajax, security, forms

I have a form which when submitted checks for a CSRF token and validates it. I'm trying to have the same security when I submit the form with ajax. But the ajax request doesn't submit the form itself, it just sends the data to the url with a post request. What would happen if the ajax request submitted this CSRF token with the request. On the server I will then check if the CSRF token. Does this compromise my form security in any way? Can this cause the ajax submission way to be exploited by others in some way?

Answer (score 0):

POSTing to a server and including the token should be just as secure as doing it via the form; it is just another way of doing the same thing.   Here's an example from an application I'm working on:

```
        var getCookie = function(name) {
            var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
            return r ? r[1] : undefined;
        };

        var args = {
            _xsrf : getCookie("_xsrf"),
           // other args added
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : "/ajaxhandler",
            data : args,
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
          // .. the rest as usual
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should be secure.  As long as JavaScript running on another domain can't read the token. This can happen, for instance this [JSON abuse used against gmail](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2007/01/gmail-xsrf-json-call-back-hackery.html).